# Skipping stage passing variables

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am sorry to post a question that may be easily tested, but I don't have an OGL4+ hardware at the moment and I have to make some design decision beforehand so I wanted a clear scenario.

Suppose I have a variable produced in the vertex shader that I will not need until the fragment shader. If I also include the tessellation shaders can I do something like:

```
//// Vertex shader

out vec3 foo;

// Ignore foo in tessellation control and eval shader


//// Fragment shader
in vec3 foo;
```

Or I **necessarily** have to do something like:

```
//// Vertex shader

out vec3 fooCS;

// TCS
in vec3 fooCS;
out vec3 fooES;

//TES
in vec3 fooES;
out vec3 foo;


//// Fragment shader
in vec3 foo;
```

And in the latter case, should I use the `[]` qualifier to pass the variables?

Comment: Each shader stage can only feed into the next one, thus you do need to pass these variables all the way through. I'm not sure what the `[]` qualifier is though. (Which is why I've held off posting this as an answer)

Answer (score 1):

Every shader stage that actually exists in your pipeline is responsible for feeding *all* values to the next one. So if you want to pass a variable from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, every intervening stage *must* provide that variable.

And this makes sense. Take tessellation. The whole point of tessellation is that new vertices get created. How could OpenGL automatically map the vertex shader output to arbitrary tessellation functions? Indeed, doing that mapping is why the TES *exists;* that's what it's for.

Same thing with the GS. It can generate new primitives and vertices.

As for using `[]`, you will have to use it as is appropriate for the inputs and outputs of that particular stage.